# Copy data to another database

Tags: sql-server, migration

I would like to know how to copy all the data from a database X1 into a database X2 on SQL Server please.

Answer (score 4):

Some options are:

1. Create a backup and restore as a different name (if on same server):
   https://www.nucleustechnologies.com/blog/restore-sql-database-with-a-different-name/
2. [Script a database by using the Generate Scripts option](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ssms/tutorials/scripting-ssms?view=sql-server-ver15#script-a-database-by-using-the-generate-scripts-option) using Types of data to script set to Schema and Data;
3. Use the [Import and Export Data with the SQL Server Import and Export Wizard](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/integration-services/import-export-data/import-and-export-data-with-the-sql-server-import-and-export-wizard?view=sql-server-ver15).

Comment: **1)** [Script a database by using the Generate Scripts option](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ssms/tutorials/scripting-ssms?view=sql-server-ver15#script-a-database-by-using-the-generate-scripts-option) using **Types of data to script** set to Schema and Data; **2)** Use the [Import and Export Data with the SQL Server Import and Export Wizard](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/integration-services/import-export-data/import-and-export-data-with-the-sql-server-import-and-export-wizard?view=sql-server-ver15). These are two other options you could add to your answer to improve it =)

Answer (score 0):

I think [JShark's answer](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/276518/22336) covers the simplest ways to tackle this, but if you want something very quick and PS-based check out [DBATools](https://docs.dbatools.io/#Copy-DbaDatabase). Even if you're not too familiar with PowerShell, the Copy-DbaDatabase command in the link is pretty easy to use depending on your se